# Reflexivity of the preference relation

Tags: relations, economics

Advanced Microeconomic Theory by Jhele and Reny states the axioms of consumer choice: completeness, transitivity, continuity, local-non satiation, strict monotonicity, convexity and strict convexity.

It is clear that the preference relation is also reflexive. I thought I could derive it from completeness, but the book states completeness is the comparison between two distinct consumption plans.

That is,

$$\forall\vec{x},\vec{y}\in X,\text{ }\vec{x}\succsim\vec{y}\vee\vec{y}\succsim\vec{x}.$$

Shouldn't it be stated as

$$\forall\vec{x},\vec{y}\in X,\text{ }\vec{x}\succsim\vec{y}\vee\vec{y}\succsim\vec{x}\vee\vec{x}=\vec{y}?$$

Or is reflexivity implied by some of the axioms? What am I missing?

Comment: You don't need the last clause $x=y$ in the definition of completeness since you define the preference relation as a weak inequality so $x$ is always preferred to itself. If you started with a strong inequality definition for preference you would need to include that third case for completeness.

Comment: In the third edition of Jehle and Reny, Axiom 1 (Completeness) reads: "For all $x^1$ and $x^2$ in $X$, either $x^1 \succsim x^2$ or $x^2  \succsim x^1$." The does not say anything about whether the two elements of the set $X$ are distinct (there is no condition $x^1\neq x^2$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $\forall\vec{x},\vec{y}\in X,\text{ }\vec{x}\succsim\vec{y}\vee\vec{y}\succsim\vec{x}.$ Take some arbitrary $\vec{z}$. It follows by plugging in $\vec{x} = \vec{y} = \vec{z}$ that $\vec{z} \succsim \vec{z} \lor \vec{z} \succsim \vec{z}$, which is equivalent to saying $\vec{z} \succsim \vec{z}$. So we have proved $\forall \vec{z} (\vec{z} \succsim \vec{z})$, which is the definition of reflexivity.